# At what l/d ratio will a frame element start to behave as a shell element?

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, numerics, numerical-modelling, solid-mechanics

I'm working in ETABS. There are few columns of dimension 300mmx1400mm. The height of building is 36.6 meter above ground level and the dimension of building is 26mx68m. I'm getting the time period of this model as 3.08 which is way too high. Hence i thought of changing the above mentioned columns to shell elements which will be more stiffer. Is this procedure correct?

Comment: Very unlikely the difference in frequencies is due to "shell" behavior of the members. Where did your correct estimate of the frequency come from and what does the mode shape look like? What does the mode shape from your FE model look like? Provide a plot of this.

Comment: I'm glad there's someone here (@BillGreene) who even understands what the question is about :-)